# mysql sum where sum result is Null

Tags: mysql

I am using the below query which works fine if result of `sum(otb.special_discount)` is not null. but if the result is null the whole result of the sum query is returning null.

How I should correct this query that is for exampple `sum(otb.total_charges)` is 10000 and `sum(otb.special_discount)` is Null, I want the result to be 10000.

```
SELECT ott.test_name, (sum(otb.total_charges)- sum(otb.special_discount))as test_charges,
count(otb.id)count
from opd_test_bill otb,opd_test_type ott where otb.bill_type='p'
and otb.test_name=ott.id 
and date between '2015-04-26 16:00:59' and '2015-04-27 06:00:00' 
group by ott.test_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
SELECT ott.test_name, (COALESCE(sum(otb.total_charges),0)- COALESCE(sum(otb.special_discount),0))as test_charges,
count(otb.id)count
from opd_test_bill otb,opd_test_type ott where otb.bill_type='p'
and otb.test_name=ott.id 
and date between '2015-04-26 16:00:59' and '2015-04-27 06:00:00' 
group by ott.test_name
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

*Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.*

You can also use 'IFNULL':

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

```
SELECT ott.test_name, (IFNULL(sum(otb.total_charges),0)- IFNULL(sum(otb.special_discount),0))as test_charges,
count(otb.id)count
from opd_test_bill otb,opd_test_type ott where otb.bill_type='p'
and otb.test_name=ott.id 
and date between '2015-04-26 16:00:59' and '2015-04-27 06:00:00' 
group by ott.test_name
```

Comment: Great, It works just fine, BTW - how COALESCE works can you please explain a bit?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE function :

```
     SELECT ott.test_name, 
     (sum(otb.total_charges)- COALESCE(sum(otb.special_discount),0))as test_charges,
     count(otb.id)count
     from opd_test_bill otb join opd_test_type ott 
     on otb.test_name=ott.id     
     where otb.bill_type='p'and date between '2015-04-26 16:00:59' and '2015-04-27 06:00:00' 
      group by ott.test_name
```